# SQLite UPDATE Value Using Foreign Key Reference

Tags: sqlite, sql-update, foreign-keys, left-join

Given three tables with one table serving as a junction table which contains two foreign key columns, I'm trying to make an insert so that, given a `TableA.prefix`, `TableA.number`, `TableB.prefix`, and `TableB.number`, I can update the `JunctionTable.is_archived` column for the matching row in `JunctionTable`:

So while the matching row in JunctionTable currently looks like:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|     id     |     tblA_id     |     tblB_id     |     is_archived     |
|     3      |        7        |       98        |          0          |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

And matching rows in TableA and TableB look like:

TableA

```
+----------------------------------------------+
|     id     |     prefix     |     number     |
|     7      |      CLA       |       754      |
+----------------------------------------------+
```

TableB

```
+----------------------------------------------+
|     id     |     prefix     |     number     |
|     98     |      RED       |       221      |
+----------------------------------------------+
```

I'd like to UPDATE the `is_archived` value like so:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|     id     |     tblA_id     |     tblB_id     |     is_archived     |
|     3      |        7        |       98        |          1          |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I've tried a few different statements based on information found [here](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-update/) but they aren't valid:

```
UPDATE JunctionTable 
    SET is_archived = "1" 
        WHERE tblAid = 
            (SELECT id FROM TableA WHERE prefix = "CLA" AND number = 754) 
        AND tblB.id = 
            (SELECT id FROM TableB WHERE prefix = "RED" AND number = 221)



UPDATE JunctionTable 
    SET is_archived = "1" 
        WHERE (
            LEFT JOIN TableA ON JunctionTable.tblA_id=TableA.id 
                WHERE TableA.course_prefix = "CLA" AND TableA.course_number = 754 
            LEFT JOIN TableB ON JunctionTable.tblB_id=TableB.id 
                WHERE TableB.course_prefix = "RED" AND TableB.course_number = 221)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first query, it looks like the problems are the names of the ID columns in your Junction table ("tblAid" and "tblB.id"), and you're using double quotes instead of single quotes. This should work:

```
UPDATE JunctionTable 
SET is_archived = 1 
    WHERE tblA_id = 
        (SELECT id FROM TableA WHERE prefix = 'CLA' AND number = 754) 
    AND tblB_id = 
        (SELECT id FROM TableB WHERE prefix = 'RED' AND number = 221)
```

Comment: I am using the UPDATE statement with PHP so I kept the double quotes, and it worked like a charm - thanks!